# Postgres dialect not working in sequelize -m

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Running Sequelize -m

in my config.json

```
"development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "**********",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "protocol": "postgres",
    "port": 5432,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
},
```

getting error:

```
sequelize -m
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/transaction-manager.js:10
    throw new Error("The dialect " + sequelize.getDialect() + " is not support
          ^
Error: The dialect postgres is not supported.
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/transaction-manager.js:10:11)
    at new module.exports.Sequelize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:128:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/bin/sequelize:225:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Is there a problem in my config, or something else that could be the issue?

Answer (score 14):

I've stumbled upon the same problem. You should install `pg` module globally. Here's the command:

```
npm install -g pg
```

Answer (score 7):

Nope!

You need to install pg-hstore.

See here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2949

Answer (score 6):

You need to have

```
$ npm install pg --save
$ npm install pg-hstore --save
$ npm install sequelize --save
```

Also create the database separately, sequelize doesn't create the db for you.

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

// make sure you have created the database using pg Admin III 
var sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/yourdbname");

var Person = sequelize.define('person', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

Person.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  return Person.create({
    firstName: 'jj',
    lastName: 'Hancock'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've run `npm install --save pg` inside sequelize directory and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Did an strace on the application. It seems Sequelize v2.x was searching for 'pg-native.

`npm install -g pg-native`

Answer (score 2):

I have run root@# "***npm install pg pg-hstore sequelize  --save***"
and it resolve the issue for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The doc says:

> With the release of Sequelizev1.6.0, the library got independent from
>   specific dialects.  That mean, that you'll have to add the respective
>   dialect library yourself. Another  option is the use of the sequelize
>   packages that ship the dialect libraries as well.

Then you might have missed to require the library, see [Sequelize docs](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#dialects).

Comment: I have the pg module installed and running with sequelize in the application. The only place it doesn't work is when running the binary for migrations. at this point is where I get the 'error'. The dialect is working throughout the rest of the application

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed thread of this issue can be found in the [sequelize issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6907)

Installing [pg-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-native) `npm i pg-native` solved for my case (also suggested above by [Hakkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122904/hakkar)).

- I was having the same issue while using `npm` so the problem is not linked to `yarn` (as suggested above)
- I can't install it globally, as suggested, because I need it to run in a Lambda function
- I installed `npm i --save pg` and also installed `npm i -D @types/pg` because I'm using TS
- I imported `import * as pg from 'pg';` and also `import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';`, then `const s = new Sequelize(connecStr, {dialectModule: pg})`
- I do not need to manually configure webpack and do not want to include it just for the sake of making a SQL query
- Also tried to reboot `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

After installing pg-native it solved my case.

Hope that helps

Related issues:

- [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/109)